# Loading integer into PostgreSQL with SQLalchemy - error Invalid input syntax for integer

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following code to load CSV file into PostgreSQL DB. It works fine like that:

```
def Load_Data(file_name):
    data = genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=',', skip_header=1, dtype=[('curr', numpy.unicode_, 10),
                                                                      ('code', numpy.unicode_, 10),
                                                                      ('exp', numpy.unicode_, 10),
                                                                      ('cryp', numpy.unicode_, 10)])

    return data.tolist()


Base = declarative_base()


class CurrencyDetails(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'curr_det'
    curr = Column(VARCHAR(10), primary_key=True)
    code = Column(VARCHAR(10))
    exp = Column(VARCHAR(10))
    cryp = Column(VARCHAR(10), nullable=False)
```

However the exp columnt, is actualy Integer datatype and I would prefer to create table column exp with integer type. I have tried to use

```
exp = Column(Integer)
```

But then I get the error

> DataError('(psycopg2.DataError) invalid input syntax for integer

The source csv file has some empty values '', I assume that is the problem. Can I load is somehow as Integer without modifying the file?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: After you've loaded the file into python, just replace all instances of `''` with `None`, before writing to the db.

Comment: You could also look at the [converters](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) param of the `genfromtext()` func.